# impossible to create text file in PHP (nginx)

Tags: php, nginx

I have this in the root of my website directory:

```
$filename = "test01.txt"; //the name of our file.
$content = "This is our test file"; //what we will be writing to our file.
$strlength = strlen($content); //gets the length of our $content string.
$create = fopen($filename, "w"); //uses fopen to create our file.
$write = fwrite($create, $content, $strlength); //writes our string to our file.
$close = fclose($create); //closes our file
echo("File Created, Click <a href='$filename'> Here </a> to view it.");
```

I just want to create a text file with a php script, but it doesn't work.
Have you any idea ?
Thank you

Comment: What error do you get? Are you sure the folder is writable?

Comment: Can you physically see the file in that folder?

Maybe the href link is not working ...

Comment: When i refresh my FTP, i see nothing. I get 0 error. I dont understand what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

make sure the dir is writable (group www), and the you can also use function file_put_contents

file_put_contents($create, $content);